# Should I use std::atomic or std::mutex to avoid the thread race?

Tags: c++, multithreading

What is the better way to avoid the data race in this specific scenario?

I am writing a program where a class has some variable and creates a detached (async/parallel) thread to update its private variable in an infinite while loop. Also, this class has a function that accesses its private variable time to time in the main thread:

```
#include "UART.h"
class Example
{
private:
  double x;
  double y;
  UART &uart;
public:
  Example::Example(UART u) : uart(u), x(0), y(0) {};

  void Example::run()
  {
     while(1)
     {
         x = uart.read() // Here x is being filled with some other values
     }
  }

  void Example::getX()
  {
     // Data race
      y = this->x*2;
   }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Example example(u);
  std::thread t1(&Example::run, example);
  t1.detach();

  example.getX();
}
```

So with the code above, what is the better solution to avoid a data race and undefined behavior of `x`?

Is it having `mutex` in function `getx()`:

```
// mtx will be created in Example private member sector
void Example::getX()
{
   mtx.lock();
   y = this->x*2;
   mtx.unlock();
}
```

Or is it better to make `x` as atomic?

```
std::atomic<double> x;
```

Comment: The mutex doesn't help if it is only locked in `getX`. Just use the atomic.

Comment: @tkausl Why mutex won't help? Isn't ```getX``` the only function where data race can occur? Or am I missing something

Comment: A mutex will also work but it should be done consistently, i.e. wrap *all* accesses to `x` in mutex lock/unlock (better yet lock_guard). But yea, an atomic will suffice in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only is an `atomic` enough here, but `memory_order_relaxed` (rather than simple assignment) suffices, since there are no other memory writes that need to be made available to another thread.

Comment: @David Herring are you saying that because I am not writing into the memory (into X) using a second thread I do not really need to worry about the data race?

Comment: @Edmund: I’m saying that stronger memory orderings (including the default when you convert or assign a `std::atomic` object, which is `memory_order_seq_cst`) can be used to protect *other* memory locations that are not atomic at all.  That’s how mutexes typically work internally.